# iptables / nftables: Forward UDP data to multiple targets

Tags: linux, networking, iptables, forwarding, nftables

I need to create iptables rules for the following scenario:

- Different hosts send UDP data to host `A`. The target port is `1234`.
- Host `A` (8.2.3.4) redirects the received UDP data to hosts `B1` (7.2.3.1), `B2` (22.93.12.3), ... `Bn` (12.42.1.3); the IP addresses are just for illustrations there.
- **It is not about load balancing**, so every host `B1`, `B2`, ... `Bn` must receive **all** packages. Therefore, host `A` has to **duplicate** the packages.
- The forwarded packages must have the correct target IP (`B1`, `B2`, ... `Bn`) and source IP (host `A`)
- I cannot change anything on the initial hosts which send data to host `A`
- I cannot change anything on the target hosts `B1`, `B2`, ... `Bn`
- The hosts `B1`, `B2`, ... `Bn` do not have to be able to answer back

I've tried to solve this with `PREROUTING` / `mangle`:

```bsh
HOST_A=8.2.3.4
HOST_B1=7.2.3.1
HOST_B2=22.93.12.3
...
HOST_BN=12.42.1.3

iptables -F -t mangle
iptables -t mangle -A PREROUTING -d $HOST_A -p udp --dport 1234 -j TEE --gateway $HOST_B1
iptables -t mangle -A PREROUTING -d $HOST_A -p udp --dport 1234 -j TEE --gateway $HOST_B2
...
iptables -t mangle -A PREROUTING -d $HOST_A -p udp --dport 1234 -j TEE --gateway $HOST_BN

iptables -L -t mangle
```

The hosts `B1`, `B2`, ... `Bn` do not seem to receive the data. Does anyone know what is wrong? Debugging is actually quite tricky (I found not really a way to do it).

Thanks

Comment: Probably, the same problem is described here: https://serverfault.com/questions/236503/need-to-duplicate-udp-packets-to-multiple-destinations-via-iptables and here: https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/553334/setting-up-udp-packets-to-two-different-destinations-using-iptables-and-prerouti The second link should help you ;)

Comment: Thanks for the links. The second one works for 2 targets, but I'm currently failing to generalize it for n targets.

Comment: Try to piping via socat. With "iptables mangle" you should be able to PREROUTING to more than two destination in the same way - just add the next bellow.

Comment: If you want n targets, the question should be changed accordingly, preferably with a full example (with IP addresses etc.) so no mis-comprehension of the problem happens. Also using "kernel tools" rather than userland tools (socat or a dedicated tool) might become increasingly awkward. And finally. Do the targets ever have to reply to the source? Because this can change possible methods. I'd also consider nftables instead of iptables there.

Comment: The targets do not have to replay. I'll improve the question and try nftables. Thanks

Comment: While it can be understood from the TEE target and comments, you should state explictly that it's about **duplicating** 1 packet to n duplicates, and for example not about load-balancing. Also, if you're open to accepting nftables in answers, you could add the nftables tag.

Comment: Thx for the comments. They are very helpful:)! All hosts usually only have one interface (eth0). Host A is listening on port 1234 for UDP packets and each packet it receives should be sent to the hosts B1, B2, ... BN (they also listen on port 1234). Host A does nothing else. It can be assumed that the sources already know the IP address of host A, so they just send their data to it.

Comment: never mind. deleted my 2 last comments: source address becomes A's, not original host's. I didn't read it carefully.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

### Samplicator

There's a tool that matches all the criteria, [samplicator](https://github.com/sleinen/samplicator):

> **UDP Samplicator**
>
> This small program receives UDP datagrams on a given port, and resends
> those datagrams to a specified set of receivers. In addition, a
> sampling divisor N may be specified individually for each receiver,
> which will then only receive one in N of the received packets.

An example command to run on host A that would match OP's examples for destinations B1 B2 and Bn:

```
samplicate -p 1234 7.2.3.1/1234 22.93.12.3/1234 12.42.1.3/1234
```

That's probably the more reasonable thing to do.

---

### nftables

For an unreasonable approach, this could be done in-kernel, either with *iptables* with difficulty (example for only two duplicates in my answer in this [UL SE Q/A](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/553334/setting-up-udp-packets-to-two-different-destinations-using-iptables-and-prerouti/553707#553707)), or with *nftables* which can do [stateless NAT](https://wiki.nftables.org/wiki-nftables/index.php/Mangle_packet_header_fields) avoiding some complexity related to *conntrack zones*.

*nftables* uses *iptables*'s [TEE](https://manpages.debian.org/iptables/iptables-extensions.8#TEE) equivalent: [dup](https://manpages.debian.org/nftables/nft.8#DUP_STATEMENT).

> **DUP STATEMENT**
>
> The dup statement is used to duplicate a packet and send the copy to a
> different destination.
>
> **dup to** *device*
> **dup to** *address* **device** *device*

Note: the first syntax can't be used in the `ip` family, but only in the `netdev` family which would add multiple issues, one among them being having to guess the correct MAC addresses (in case of Ethernet interface) which would also need alterations, so becomes less practical.

*dup* has the same behaviour as *TEE*: the duplicate must immediately be "evacuated" to a gateway on an interface (gateway meaning an IPv4 address that, if relevant for the type of interface, is used only to resolve using ARP the destination MAC address, but is not in the IP packet itself) probably to avoid it being processed abnormally by the rest of the routing stack. **The final destination cannot be the *gateway* address** (unless it happens to be in the same LAN).

Here a special routing setup is done in order to inject back the already *statelessly* SNATed (to A's own address) / DNATed (to final destinations) packets to the host itself so that it will further route them to their destination as if it had actually been emitted by itself. This requires to [accept *receiving* one own's local IP address](https://git.kernel.org/pub/scm/linux/kernel/git/stable/linux.git/tree/Documentation/networking/ip-sysctl.txt?h=linux-5.4.y#n1214), and disabling all [reverse path filter](https://git.kernel.org/pub/scm/linux/kernel/git/stable/linux.git/tree/Documentation/networking/ip-sysctl.txt?h=linux-5.4.y#n1225) on the receiving *veth* interface (thus requiring to do this on the *all* setting as well). It could still be re-enabled explicitly on *eth0* if needed.

Setup on host A in addition to its initial running network configuration (with its single interface *eth0*):

```
HOST_A=8.2.3.4

ip link add name vethinj up type veth peer name vethgw
ip link set vethgw up
sysctl -w net.ipv4.conf.vethgw.forwarding=1
sysctl -w net.ipv4.conf.vethgw.accept_local=1
sysctl -w net.ipv4.conf.vethgw.rp_filter=0
sysctl -w net.ipv4.conf.all.rp_filter=0
ip route add $HOST_A/32 dev vethinj
```

There's no additional IP address to assign. Linux using the weak [host model](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Host_model), the IP address on *eth0* is available on *vethgw* so is reachable as gateway through *vethinj* once the route is added.

The *nftables* rules in the file `multiply.nft`, to be loaded with `nft -f multiply.nft` below will:

- match the packet to multiply
- do a *stateless* SNAT (`ip saddr set`) to A's own address. This doesn't involve *conntrack*'s NAT.
- for each destination Bx, do a stateless DNAT (`ip daddr set`) to destination HOST_Bx and duplicate the packet to injection's side of the *veth* pair, using A's own address as gateway.
- drop the remaining altered original because it's of no use anymore.

`multiply.nft`:

```
define HOST_A=8.2.3.4
define HOST_B1=7.2.3.1
define HOST_B2=22.93.12.3
define HOST_Bn=12.42.1.3

table ip multiply
delete table ip multiply

table ip multiply {
        chain c {
                type filter hook prerouting priority -300; policy accept;
                iif != vethgw ip daddr $HOST_A udp dport 1234 ip saddr set $HOST_A goto cmultiply
        }

        chain cmultiply {
                jump cdnatdup
                drop
        }

        chain cdnatdup {
                ip daddr set $HOST_B1 dup to $HOST_A device vethinj
                ip daddr set $HOST_B2 dup to $HOST_A device vethinj

                ip daddr set $HOST_Bn dup to $HOST_A device vethinj
        }
}
```

To add a new destination 192.0.2.2 after this, one can do manually:

```
nft add rule ip multiply cdnatdup ip daddr set 192.0.2.2 dup to 8.2.3.4 device vethinj
```

Below, a text schematic for single packet coming from S2 and duplicated to B1 B2 and Bn:

```
S1 →┄┄┄┄┄╮                        ╭┄┄┄┄┄┄┄┄→ B1
S2 →┄┄┄╮ ┊                        ┊ ╭┄┄┄┄┄┄→ B2
...    ┊ ┊                        ┊ ┊       ...
Sn →┄╮ ┊ ┊                        ┊ ┊ ╭┄┄┄┄→ Bn
     ┊ ┊ ╰┄┄  ┄      ┌──────┐↗┄┄┄┄╯ ┊ ┊
     ┊ ╰┄┄┄┄┄┄┄┄┄┄┄┄→│ eth0 │→┄┄┄┄┄┄╯ ┊
     ╰┄┄┄┄┄┄ ┄       └──────┘↘┄┄┄┄┄┄┄┄╯
                    ↙      ↖↖↖
             snat  ↯        ↑↑↑  internal
  nftables:  dnat  ⇊    A   ↑↑↑  routing
            & dup ↓↓↓       ↑↑↑
               ┌───────┐  ┌───────┐
               │vethinj│  │vethgw │
               └───────┘  └───────┘
                    ╰─── ⇶ ───╯ 
                   virtual wire
```

Note: as this NAT wasn't handled by *conntrack* there's no possibility to have B1 B2...Bn answer back to the original source, but this was waived by OP.

Comment: I'll try your very well explained solution tomorrow! Thank you very much! (thx for the nice illustration!)

Comment: I've tested the nft rules and it works just great! Thank you very much!